# Neewer QC trigger not working with Youngnuo speedlite 560 III + cannon 6D

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-flash

In full **manual mode**, The trigger works if the flash is mounted on top of the trigger, which itself is mounted on the hotshoe of the camera.

However it doesnt work as a **remote trigger** (rx mode). no signal. the trigger light/infrared stays flashing.

Im attaching pictures for reference.I believe the settings are correct.

There are no youtube videos i could find, or manuals and articles on google.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect the Newer QC trigger transmitter and Godox flash receiver use different communication protocols and are not compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radio receiver in the YN560 III uses the Yongnuo YN560 communication protocol.

The transmitter in the Neewer trigger does not communicate using Yongnuo's YN560 protocol.

In other words, the transmitter and the receiver do not speak the same language.

Just because they both use the 2.4GHz radio band (like thousands of other short-range wireless radio devices) doesn't mean they speak the same language so that the receiver can understand what the transmitter is saying.

To use the built-in receiver if the YN560 III you need a transmitter that uses the YN560 protocol, such as the Yongnuo YN560-TX or YN560-TX II.

To use the Neewer QC trigger you need to either use a Neewer flash that is compatible with the QC (not all Neewer flashes are, in fact most are not). You *might* be able to attach a Neewer QC compatible receiver to the hot foot of the Yongnuo YN560 III and trigger it that way.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Very helpful.